# How Can I modify a request header value from A to B by using Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Currently we are using Haproxy as a software loadbalancer.

I have an assignment, where I need to inspect each and request coming into my application and I need to look for a specific header (let's say Accept header) and I need to modify the value of header from A --> B.

Could you please guide me how can I do this by using HAPROXY.

Regards,
-Srini.

Answer (score 2):

To replace one request header with another, example:

```
Accept: application/json # existing value
Accept: application/xml  # desired value
```

Test the current value then set a header with the desired header.

```
http-request set-header Accept application/xml if { hdr(accept) -m str application/json }
```

Using `http-request set-header` removes any/all existing headers with the same name, which is what you would wanrtin this case.  Using `-m str` specifies a case-sensitive string match on the value.  Header name matching is always case-insensitive.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-http-request

Comment: Thank you Michael for guiding me here..
I have tried above example to replace the Content-Type value, but I am failed to replace the header.
here is my configuration
frontend er-ba-http-in 
               bind 0.0.0.0:30500
                              http-request set-header Content-Type text/xml if { hdr(Content-Type) -m str application/x-www-form-urlencoded }
               use_backend er-ba-cluster

backend er-ba-cluster
               balance roundrobin
                              option httpchk GET /health
                              http-check expect status 200